# JavaScript VS Handlebars.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, handlebars.js

What are the benefits of using Handlebars.js, or any other such libraries, compared to just using JavaScript? So far I have not found anything in Handlebars that I cant do in just javascript.

Comment: I have also not found anything in high-level languages that I can't just do with a few thousand lines of assembly code. Higher-level abstractions are not only about getting things done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript libraries make it easier and quicker to do things in JavaScript, anything a library can do, you can do yourself in JavaScript. But why would you? In pure JavaScript, if I wanted to select a element by id, I'd have to do this:

```
document.getElementById("coolId");
```

Or in [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) (a JavaScript library) I could just do this:

```
$("#coolId");
```

It's quicker and easier than using pure JavaScript. Hence that's why I use JQuery to select elements and why I many different libraries - because they allow me to do things much quicker and easier than doing it myself in pure JavaScript, think of libraries as 'shortcuts' to achieving your goal functionality.

**Edit: The drawbacks**

However, whilst JavaScript libraries (generally) make our lives easier, as developers. They do come with drawbacks, including; large JavaScript files to download, taking longer for JavaScript engines to execute the code and, therefore, makes our code less efficient. For more on this, here are some links:

- [Advantages of using pure JavaScript over JQuery](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/166273/advantages-of-using-pure-javascript-over-jquery)
- [What are the advantages and disadvantages of different JavaScript libraries?](http://www.quora.com/What-are-the-advantages-and-disadvantages-of-different-JavaScript-libraries)
- [The Pros And Cons Of JavaScript Micro-Frameworks](http://addyosmani.com/blog/prosconsmicroframeworks/)

Thanks to Lix for the reminder.

Comment: Quicker? Probably not... It'll always be faster to use "native" commands rather than a libraries abstraction that in the end of the day just makes the same native call.

Comment: I meant quicker for me to type, not quicker for a JavaScript engine to execute.

Comment: You'll have to mention that distinction - it makes a big difference. Sometimes you want to make life easier for the developer and sometimes you want to make life easier for the JS engine.... It's maintainability vs performance.

Comment: Hi thank you for this, I understand. My point was not for JQuery but handlebars. It seems that the shortcuts that we get with handlebars are not really short cuts. They seems about the same length. There is also no added functionality, where as with JQuery we have added functionality.